# how implement health check in the grpc-dart implementation?

Tags: dart, grpc, kubernetes-health-check, grpc-dart

I am trying to add grpc health check to my dart backend, but it seems that the grpc implementation in dart does not bring the service for the kubernetes health check, as in other grpc implementations, as is the case of java https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/services/HealthStatusManager.html#getHealthService--.

how can i do this in dart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC provides a [`health.proto`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto), described [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md).

Some of the language implementations provide implementations for it too. I know Go does [grpc_health_v1](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/health/grpc_health_v1) and it appears Java does too.

The proto is straightforward and, if the Dart SDK doesn't include an implementation, it should be straightforward for you to create one.

I recommend you retain the proto` package name mapped to Dart's package naming.

Comment: Yes, I did, but the problem is that when I implemented it on my own grpc_health_probe https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe it doesn't work. it throws me an error saying like don't implement the health check, anyway I already implemented it myself and made a client that runs a rpc, and I run it to it with livenessProbe and readinessProbe. Thanks for your reply.